# What is the advantage of running asynchronous code in middleware i.e. redux-thunk or redux-saga

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-saga

I am just learning how to implement redux into my react projects and I am trying to understand the advantage of running asynchronous code in middleware for redux state changes. Why wouldn't we just run the asynchronous code at the component level and then dispatch different actions on the completion of the asynchronous code at the component level?

Comment: If your asynchronous code modifies local componen's state **only** you're not obliged to perform those actions from within middleware. Furthermore, you're [encouraged](https://redux.js.org/faq/organizing-state/#organizing-state) to keep locally what's not required by other components or even not required by this component later on.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes depends on your situation u have to call actions at same time u need middlewars for async actions and its clearer and simpler and more sync to call your apis in your actions.instead of fetch it in your component then pass it to your action.